# Wordpress Custom Theme Pagination Issue

Tags: php, css, wordpress, pagination, page-numbering

I work for 2 sister companies and we have copied the template of one website to another for most of the functionality.

For some reason, I cannot get the pagination to work as it does on the one website. We are using a custom theme so I can't seem to get any plugins to work.

The pagination works well here: https://clcanursing.co.uk/news/ and I want to be able to replicate how it looks and how it reacts to tablet and mobile devices. I am trying to copy it onto this page: http://clcacalldirect.com/blog/ but it fails here.

Any help would be appreciated!!

Thanks,
Andy

Comment: What have you tried so far? Is there a specific part of the code which you believe is broken?

Comment: Hi JamieMMX, I basically copied all of the pagination code across. I then added some custom css and that pushes the next and previous to each side of the page but then I lose the page numbers, and then when scaling the page down to devices, the next and previous buttons overlap.

Comment: Please see my answer below. If you use Google Chrome's dev tools then you can easily see which elements have matching styles, and which dont. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like your issue is CSS related. You're missing some styles (like the one below). Make sure you're copying over all styles.

Use dev tools to see the differences between the two slices of code.

**EDIT:**
The below code gives you the exact style and functionality on tablet/mobile

```
@media (max-width: 1200px) {
    .pagination .default--button {
        border-radius: 0;
        width: 49% !important;
        text-align: center;
        margin-top: 70px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you JamieMMX, I will keep looking into it :)

Comment: @ac363 - Check the most recent edit, that will fix your issue on mobile/tablet

Comment: @ac363 - Did this help?

Comment: Hi JamieMMX, I have managed to sort it. I had missed some styling and also 2 pieces of pagination code. The page numbers were then not reactive owing to a "max-width" restriction which was resctricting it.